# What's the origin of the saying, "There's no accounting for taste"?

Tags: etymology, popular-refrains

I hear it all the time in arguments over subjective judgements:

> There's no accounting for taste.

Where does this saying come from? Is it a quote or old proverb?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an English adaptation of a Latin saying:

> De gustibus non est disputandum.

Meaning literally *regarding taste, there is no dispute*. The phrase seems to be of medieval origin. The origin is accepted as [Scholastic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism) writings because of the grammar, which is atypical. A more faithful Latin rendering of the phrase might be:

> De gustatibus non disputandum.

There's some uncertainty about whether *gustus* (*gustibus*) or *gustatus* (*gustatibus*) is more appropriate.

Comment: Jinx! Well, you got it first.

Comment: Umm. Probably not a "Roman proverb" then. But even if it was, in the end this is simply an obvious thing to say - regardless of what language it was first said in.

Comment: @Fumble - it's weird that you have not frequently heard this figure of speech.

Comment: @Joe Blow: I've heard it and said it all my life, it seems. I just don't think "the Romans said it", or "the priests said it" means much for a simple observation like this.

Comment: @Fumble, hmm, but the guy is simply asking "What's the origin?"  It's a figure of speech - so, what's the origin?  Seems like a reasonable question.  (I for one did not know it was a "latin phrase," but that interests me.  It would be interesting to furthermore learn what historical period it originated in - but it appears we just don't know that.)  I believe I understand what you are asserting, you repeat it is a **simple observation** and hence (I believe you mean) it's rather "sub- figure-of-speech." But it is a figure of speech - so what's the origin?

Comment: @Joe Blow: I guess. Although my first reaction on reading the Latin version would probably be "Oh! They had the same insight we do!". And mentally translate their version as "You can't argue with matters of taste", not see it as the "original" version of our saying. Surely in several hundred years it could have occured to someone to say our (quite pithy) version *without* needing to see a similar sentiment expressed in Latin.

Comment: ...anyway, I've taken my shots and deleted my answer, since it's obviously getting up people's noses.

Comment: The Spanish version is _Sobre gustos no hay nada escrito_ meaning _On taste, nothing is written_. Where_written_ is an ancient way of referring to the law.

Comment: I'm very late to the party here, but I want to know the origin of the specific English wording.  Whether it was meant as a direct translation or not, the meanings are distinctly different. One is sort of philosophical, i.e. taste is by definition purely subjective and argument is by definition meant to be objective.  The other is usually used as a ("pithy"-@FumbleFingers) slight, and means something more like, I don't know where your strange taste comes from. So, anyone know where/when the English version came into being?

Comment: The earliest attestation I can find for "no accounting for taste" is a 1765 translation from the French of Bellegarde's *Models of Conversation for Persons of Polite Education*

Comment: It seems clear to me that the same phrase can easily be used in earnest (taste is subjective) or sarcastically (your taste is weird) in any language.

Answer (score 4):

It is a loan translation of the latin proverb:

**De gustibus non est disputandum**

meaning literally "there's nothing to be argued about about taste". I don't know which Latin author first used it or if it was a folk saying.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_gustibus_non_est_disputandum) claims it's probably of medieval origin.

Comment: "Accounting for" something is different from arguing about it. "Where did the stapler go?" "We can't account for it, gone missing." I think it is more about "explaining" something or justifying it rather than disputing it. The sarcasm comes in by implying that the person's taste is *inexplicable*. (Which sounds strangely like *despicable*.)